# how to count number of nodes of largest cluster?

Tags: python, networkx

I have 840 nodes and I know their correlation values. I need to build the cluster according to their correlation values and count the number of nodes of largest cluster. Here I am writing few nodes information :

```
(130, 133)  0.749956
(344, 348)  0.749876
(65, 100)  0.749863
(383, 440)  0.749825
(189, 210)  0.749766 
(100, 127)  0.749651
(127, 100)  0.749651
(312, 344)  0.749611
(172, 200)  0.749554
(200, 172)  0.749554
(157, 162)  0.749477
```

where first parenthesis indicates node information and the last one is the correlation value between the two nodes.

I tried

```
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edge(130, 133)
G.add_edge(344, 348)
G.add_edge(65, 100)
G.add_edge(383, 440)
G.add_edge(189, 210)
G.add_edge(100, 127) 
G.add_edge(127, 100)
G.add_edge(312, 344)
G.add_edge(172, 200) 
G.add_edge(200, 172)
G.add_edge(157, 162) 

G.number_of_nodes(): 16
G.number_of_edges() : 9
```

I am not able to make the connected cluster and count the number of nodes of that connected largest cluster. 
I am a newbie here.

Comment: Are only select pairs of nodes correlated, or do you have correlations for all pairs of nodes? In other words, is the graph dense or is it sparsely connected? If it is the latter, you probably want to determine the connected components (`networkx.connected_components`). Otherwise, you will need to make use of the correlation strength to define partitions/modules. This is a bit more involved.

Comment: `components = list(nx.connected_components(G)); print(components)` yields [{130, 133},
 {312, 344, 348},
 {65, 100, 127},
 {383, 440},
 {189, 210},
 {172, 200},
 {157, 162}]

Comment: yes I have all pairs correlation information, but I filtered only those pairs which have correlation values between 0.3 to 0.7. I got the adjacency matrix of correlation for all the pairs.

Comment: I have another question .. is there any way to build the network by itself other than calling individual nodes each time as I have 27232 rows containing the information about nodes and correlation.

Comment: For your last question, yes, but it should be a separate question.